# Como enviar 2 GET com input

Tags: php, html, wordpress

EXEMPLO:

```html
<form action="/" method="get">
<input class="form-control mr-md-4" type="search" placeholder="Digite aqui oque deseja..." aria-label="Search" name="s" id="search" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>">
<button type="submit"><i class="fas fa-search fa-1x" style="color: #3498db;"></i></button>
</form>
```

ELE ENVIA A URL ASSIM: site.com/?s=TERMO DA PESQUISA

MAS QUERO DEIXAR ASSIM: site.com/?s=TERMO DA PESQUISA&ref=app

COM O **&ref=app** no final da URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloque o `ref=app` no atributo `action` do formulário:
Por exemplo:

```
action="pagina.php?ref=app"
```

Ou você pode também colocar esse valor em um `input` `hidden`, assim:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ref" value="app" />
```

Comment: Mas ai ele envia assim: pagina.php?ref=app?s=TERMO.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Comment: por nada!......